# Build Multilevel Custom Type without knowing the amount of levels (Folder Structure)

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a type based on the folder structure of an EDMS.  The tbl I need to query is structure as 
ParentId
ChildId

So I do not know home many level each folder structure has.

So my question is, if I create a class/type how do I do it.  I have this

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DocumentMigrator
{
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "DocuShareFolders")]
    class objFolderStructure
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "RootElement")]
        public RootElement RootElement { get; set; }

    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "RootElement")]
    public class RootElement
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "iRootElementId")]
        public string IRootElementId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sRootElementName")]
        public string SRootElementName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sRootElementDescription")]
        public string SRootElementDescription { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folder")]
        public Folder Folder { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Folder")]
    public class Folder
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "iFolderId")]
        public string IFolderId { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sFolderDescription")]
        public string SFolderDescription { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "sFolderName")]
        public string SFolderName { get; set; }

    }
}
```

My question is how do I handle child folders inside folders, and files, which may be at any level?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a folder to contain multiple child folders this is what you want.

```
[XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Folder")]
public List<Folder> ChildFolders { get; set; }
```

All you need to do is populate the Folders list with all child folders.

You might also want to change root element from this

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RootElement")]
public class RootElement
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "iRootElementId")]
    public string IRootElementId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sRootElementName")]
    public string SRootElementName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sRootElementDescription")]
    public string SRootElementDescription { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Folder")]
    public Folder Folder { get; set; }
}
```

to this

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "RootElement")]
public class RootElement
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "iRootElementId")]
    public string IRootElementId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sRootElementName")]
    public string SRootElementName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sRootElementDescription")]
    public string SRootElementDescription { get; set; }
    [XmlArrayItem(ElementName = "Folder")]
    public List<Folder> Folders { get; set; }
}
```

So that the root element can have multiple sibling folders

You can try this piece of code in a console application to test it

```
objFolderStructure structure = new objFolderStructure();
structure.RootElement = new RootElement();
structure.RootElement.Folders = new List<Folder>()
{
    new Folder()
    {
        ChildFolders = new List<Folder>()
        {
            new Folder() { SFolderName = "blah" }
        },
        SFolderName = "some folder"
    },
    new Folder()
    {
        ChildFolders = new List<Folder>()
        {
            new Folder() { SFolderName = "blah 2" },
            new Folder() { SFolderName = "blah 2 2" },
            new Folder() { SFolderName = "blah 3" }
        },
        SFolderName = "some folder 2"
    }
};

new XmlSerializer(typeof(objFolderStructure)).Serialize(Console.Out, structure);
```

You should end up with 2 folders at root level, 1st folder has 1 child folder, 2nd folder has 3 child folders.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a fullblown copy/paste answer but intended to show the construct you are looking for. I copied/edited this from a wrapper around the google Kml format that contains a simulair nested folder idea. Folders can (amongst others) contain either (sub)folders or placemarks (points on the map).

The specific construct to look at is the use of a shared base class between File and Folder (AbstractItem) combined with the use of the XmlElement Attribute.

Note that in the resulting Xml you will find the specified name from the XmlElement ("File" and "Folder") tags and *not* "Items"

```
    public class Folder : AbstractItem
{
    [XmlElement("File", Type = typeof(File))]
    [XmlElement("Folder", Type = typeof(Folder))]
    public List<AbstractItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class File : AbstractItem
{
    // Empty
}

public abstract class AbstractItem {
    [XmlElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```